# How to send marketing cloud email from Journey builder to multiple email addresses?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have lead records in Salesforce where there are two email fields on the record containing two different values.

I want to send two different emails to both the email addresses from journey builder as soon as they are created in Salesforce, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two separate journeys, and under the Settings of the journey select the the `Default Email Address` for the email address / field you wish to send the email to. Replicate the same in the second journey but select the other Email Address Field.

You can't decided in a single journey to send different emails to two separate email address fields of the same contact record.

Answer (score 1):

You could...create two journeys instead of using 1 and focus their default email addresses on your two target fields.

You could also use a single journey where the default email address is a third field such that you:

- Use Update Contact to set Temp Email == Email 1
- Send Email (to Temp Email) [which will go to Email 1]
- Use Update Contact to set Temp Email == Email 2
- Send Email (to Temp Email) [which will now go to Email 2]

If that feels *hacky*, it's because it is. For the benefit of only having to maintain a single journey, you'd introduce a new field into your data model and some additional processes into the journey. That trade-off may or may not be worth it.